# What is going wrong here?

Tags: javascript, boolean

i made this little script to learn javascript. but i keep getting unexpected token switch..
but hoe do is set switch the corect way??

html:

```
<p id="new">test<p>
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter" />
```

js:

```
var switch = true;

if (switch == false){
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Mijn Naam!";
    var switch = true;
};
} else {
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "shiva";
    var switch = false;
};
}
```

Comment: `switch` is a reserved keyword (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) - use a different name for the variable

Comment: why you re-declare again a same variable

Comment: it shoud make the botton loop true the if statement :) is there a better way?

Comment: You probably need to learn the difference between declaring a variable and using an already declared variable. The redeclaration won't make a difference right now, but it'll bite you later.

Comment: thanks squint!! ill do that!

Answer (score 4):

how about:

```
<p id="new">test<p>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" value="enter" />

var clicked = false;

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = clicked ? "shiva" : "Mijn Naam!";
  clicked = !clicked;
};
```

Comment: is the:
clicked = !clicked; setting the clicked back to false?

Comment: yes, the clicked = !clicked line toggles the value. The exclamation mark means "not". It's another way of writing: if(clicked == true) { clicked = false; } else { clicked = true; }

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is a reserved word. You should use some variable name else.

By the way, your code is possible to be *compressed* as follows:

```
var switchOn = true;

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = 
        switchOn ? "shiva" :"Mijn Naam!";
    switchOn = !switchOn;
}
```